# Radio button to switch between variables in a JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 options (same api request, different urls) I'd like to use a switch button (Radio) to let the user choose the type of the results:

```
function ApiRequest() {

var mydata = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
var userapi = document.getElementById('userapi').value; 
var userurl = document.getElementById('userurl').value; 


$.post(
  myurl,
    JSON.stringify({
      'api_key': userapi,
      'data': mydata,
    })).then(function(sent) { 
      var s = sent
      var obj = JSON.parse(s)
      $('.score').text("Score : " + obj.results*100)
      });
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="I love writing code!" id="userinput">

<input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="1234567890" id="userapi">


  <div class="material-switch pull-right" style="padding-left: 25px">
     <input id="userurl" name="hq" type="checkbox"/>
     <label for="userurl" class="label-success"></label>
  </div>

<button class="search" onclick="ApiRequest()">Try It</button>
```

Should I use something like this?

```
if userurl == true
    myurl = 'xxxxxxxxx'
    $.post(do.stuff)

else
    myurl = '+++++++++'
    $.post(do.stuff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes exactly, do something similar as you pointed out in your question.

Your HTML with radio buttons for choosing URL could be something like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="api-url-1" name="api-url" value="my-api-url-1">
<input type="radio" id="api-url-2" name="api-url" value="my-api-url-2">
```

Get the value of the checked input:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('api-url');
var chosenURL;
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        chosenURL = radios[i].value;
        // you can break because just one radio can be selected
        break;
    }
}
```

**p.s. using jQuery all this block could be replaced with simply:**

```
var chosenURL = $('input[name="api-url"]:checked').val();
```

Then start the request with your dynamic URL:

```
$.post(
  chosenURL,
    JSON.stringify({
      'api_key': userapi,
      'data': mydata,
    })).then(function(sent) { 
      var s = sent
      var obj = JSON.parse(s)
      $('.score').text("Score : " + obj.results*100)
      });
}
```

Snippet example:

```js
function trigger() {
  var chosenURL = $('input[name="api-url"]:checked').val();
  alert(chosenURL);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="api-url-1" name="api-url" value="my-api-url-1">API URL 1
<input type="radio" id="api-url-2" name="api-url" value="my-api-url-2">API URL 2
<button onclick="trigger()">Trigger</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I assign Case A / B with checked statuts?

Comment: What's wrong with this code function ApiRequest() {

    var userdata = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
    var userapi = document.getElementById('userapi').value; 
 var userurl = document.getElementById('userurl').value; 
 

 if(!$("#userurl").is(':checked') ){
  $(this).val('1');
 }
 else
 $(this).val('0');

$("#userurl").attr("checked") ? alert("Checked") : alert("Unchecked");

}

Comment: Code not working because of - in your variables, also it's print undefined with alert function. Can you please elaborate the JQuery method. Thnaks..

Comment: @Blacksun I've added to you also a snippet with a runnable example

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm trying to print chosenURL with alert. I expect to see my-api-url-1 and my-api-url-2 not Undefined

Comment: @Blacksun did you try to execute the snippet I've added?